# how to set a timeout for a service remoting call in service fabric

Tags: c#, timeout, azure-service-fabric, remoting

I have a service fabric service which i call like this from another service :

```
var checkerProxy = new ServiceProxyFactory<ICheck>(uri);
var checker = checkerProxy.CreateSingletonServiceProxy();
success = await checker.CheckMe();
```

I want to abort the call if it takes longer than a timeout.

How do I set timeout for a remoting call in service fabric ?

Edit 1 : note i can do something like this :

```
success = checker.CheckMe().Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

but this will not abort the remoting call, but only stop waiting for the completion of the task upon a timeout and i do not have the return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set timeout in proxy using `FabricTransportRemotingSettings` :

```
            FabricTransportRemotingSettings settings = new FabricTransportRemotingSettings();
            settings.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

            return new ServiceProxyFactory(
                (h) =>
                {
                    return new FabricTransportServiceRemotingClientFactory(settings);
                });
```